# transformation between rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Given two matrices $A$, $B$ of dimension $m\times n$ where $m<n$, does there always exist a $C$ such that $AC=B$? So by question, the dimension of $C$ is $n \times n$ and a choice of $C=A^R B$, where $A^R$ is the right inverse of $A$. But I am not able to show why $C$ should be invertible. Because of an inverse exists than $C^{-1}C=C^{-1}C=Id$, but I'm not able to find such a $C$ trivially. Is there any nice resource other than Wikipedia that talks about inverses of rectangular matrices in general?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, what if $A=0$ but $B\ne0$? By the way, if $C$ exists, it is not always invertible --- just pick any $A$ and any non-invertible $C$ and define $B=AC$.

For your second question, see [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse).

Comment: Let us say A,B are non zero and full row rank. From your answer does it imply there might not exist an invertible transformation from A to B (or if AC=B, C might not be invertible?) The reason i ask is because, if C is not invertible, hence not full rank, then AC will not be full rank as well, but in my case I enforce the fact that A,B are full rank.

Comment: @post_as_guest If you have a rank requirement, please state it in your question. Anyway, the desired $C$ surely exists if both $A$ and $B$ are full-rank matrices --- just extend the rows of $A$ and $B$ to two bases of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $C$ be the corresponding change-of-basis matrix.